# Command substitution alters formatting

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to grep some log files. There are two spaces between the month and the day in the log. I can generate the date in this format with the date command but when I try to assign this to a variable I lose the extra space, why is this?

```
#Gives two spaces
date "+%b %e"
Mar  8

#Only one space
echo `date "+%b %e"`
Mar 8

VAR=$(date "+%b %e")
echo $VAR
Mar 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try quoting to keep the whitespace:

```
$ echo "$VAR"
Mar  8
   ^^
```

Some explanation is in order. If you say `echo $VAR`, you end up saying:

```
echo Mar  8
```

So `echo` gets two arguments and prints them with one space in between. If you use quotes `echo` gets a single argument which it prints as it is.